# How do I kill the solar pillar?

Tags: terraria

I'm a mage character in Terraria and I just beat the lunatic cultist. My base is set up right behind the dungeon and I have to go through the solar pillar to get anywhere else. The second I go there I die.

I have spectre armor with a hood and my weapons are the Laser Machinegun, Golden Shower, Crystal Storm, Magnet Sphere, Staff of Earth, Ice Rod, and the Nimbus Rod.

How can I beat the Solar Pillar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solar pillar is a primarily melee-based zone, where flight and jumping is severely punished. The crawltipedes are passive until you're airborne, in which they attack and kill you in just a few hits.

Slowly approach the pillar, let an enemy or two spawn, then retreat to ground outside the pillar. Defeat the enemy, and repeat. Eventually you'll learn the attack patterns of each enemy, and will be able to be more efficient at beating them. Banners will also help once you get them.

Once you have defeated enough enemies, you can use long-ranged weaponry to destroy the pillar.

Answer (score 0):

As you'll be able to tell, I have fought this pillar a lot. Here's what I've found works:

Get full Spectre Armour with the hood for health regeneration. Full Beetle Armour works as well but you might have to retreat a few times during the fight to not die.

Build a platform just above the pillar (prehaps afterwards) and use Vampire Knives (healing) and the Flaron/Vortex Blaster (for homing in) to kill the enemies. This way, you'll be able to tell when the force field is down before running into a hoard.

The Crawlipides won't attack when standing on the platform (if not hammered). Use Greater Healing Potions (and Inchor Flasks if possible). Don't jump, and try to hit the flying/charging enemies rapidly to stop them hitting you. Equip the Cross Necklace to help if you get swarmed.

Good luck and I hope this helps.